# JSON-code needed for a column in a SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have a SharePoint list. When a user inserts a new item in the list an dialog screen appears.

On the dialog screen is a text box where the user can insert text and when the user clicks on the save-button the text from the textbox will be inserted in column "Description".

By default font of the textbox is "Calibri". But what I would like is when the user closes the dialog by clicking on the Save button that in the field "Description" the font changes to "Segoe UI".

I guess I need some JSON-code for the column Description.

Who can help me? Thank you in advanced.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the image you attached to your question, I think you are using a `Multiple lines of text column with Enhanced rich text`.

Unfortunately, SharePoint JSON/column formatting **does not support** customizing `Multiple lines of text column with Enhanced rich text`.

You can check the list for supported/unsupported column types at: [JSON formatting - supported/unsupported column types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#supported-column-types)

---

You can also customize the display of columns in list view using SPFx Field customizers in SharePoint online.

Check this documentation for more information: [Build your first Field Customizer extension](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer)